# Is it possible to specify Java System Properties when running Groovy from command line

Tags: groovy

Equivalent to `java -Dprop="abc" app`, but using groovy, like `groovy -Dprop="abc" app.groovy`

Basically the same question asked [here](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Set-System-Properties-on-Command-Line-td349046.html), but negative answers there are relatively old. Anything new support this since 2007?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure; it works as-is:

```
$ cat sysenv.groovy
println System.getProperty("wat")
$ groovy -Dwat="hello" sysenv.groovy 
hello
```

Comment: Super simple, thanks.  Surprised it wasn't more evident in my search.

Comment: @JoshDiehl It's more just a Java thing, and (IIRC) an issue with Commons CLI. I think it was resolved some time ago :)